# Link a domain to a Squarespace account

Tags: url, domains

I have set up a Squarespace account and now need to link a domain I purchased elsewhere. What settings do I need to change on the domain hosted?

This is what I've got so far, however the changes don't seem to have propagated and my website still has a default page:

[image: dns and nameserver settings]

Here are the settings that [Squarespace say I need to use for GoDaddy](http://help.squarespace.com/customer/portal/articles/581579-domain-mapping-with-godaddy), but I'm on A2Hosting and confused as to how to configure everything.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need hosting if you're using Squarespace. Wherever your domain is hosted, you'll find the settings above usually under DNS settings. Check A2Hosting support info for answers on finding the right settings if your domain is hosted with them. Your domain may be managed somewhere other than your hosting account.

Comment: I've sent a ticket to a2hosting and they replied with the link to squarespace, as opposed to a link to information specific to configuring the a2hosting domain... So, no luck there.